# Unit testing a method with IServiceProvider.GetRequiredService throws No service for type '<T>'has been registered

Tags: c#, nunit, .net-6.0, moq

I have a class that takes `IServiceProvider` as an argument in constructor, and in a `Get()` method it returns an object using `IServiceProvider.GetRequiredService`. When unit testing this method to see whether it returns the expected Type of object, it throws `System.InvalidOperationException` exception with a message `No service for type '..MyType..' has been registered`. What should be the approach to unit test this one?

I have a restriction on changing the `Get()` method or `Foo` class implementation .Therefore, it is not an option.

Also, it is not possible to mock `IserviceProvider.GetRequiredService` as this is a framework extension method. Therefore, haven't used this approach.

Implementation:

```
public class Foo
{
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public Foo(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IOtherService s1, IOtherService2 s2){
       _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
       //...mapping other dependencies here    
    }

    public IType Get (string type){
        switch (type){

        //This line throws the DI exception when unit test
        //No service for type 'MyType' has been registered
        //Cannot change this implementation

        case "a": return (IType)_serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(typeof(MyType));

        //other cases here 
        //......
        }
    }
}
```

Unit test using `NUnit.Framework, Autofac.Extras.Moq, Moq`

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
  using var am = AutoMock.GetLoose();
  var foo= am.Create<Foo>();

  //DI Exception when calling this method
  //No service for type 'MyType' has been registered
  foo.Get("a");
  
 //Assert here
 //....
}
```

Really appreciate the support in resolving this.

Comment: You don't need to mock the extension method, just the `GetService` method defined in the interface. These extension methods exist, because default implementations hadn't been invented yet.

Comment: The method used in the implementation is 'GetRequiredService' not  'GetService', and that is an extension method so cannot mock that one.

Comment: And `GetRequiredService` is just an extension that calls `GetService` and validates the result. So you don't need to mock it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why do you need the `IServiceProvider` as a ctor parameter? Can't you anticipate the `MyType` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Just because an interface is involved, it doesn't mean that you *have to* replace it with a [Test Double](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html). In this case it seems easier to just use [ServiceCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollection):

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    var sc = new ServiceCollection();
    sc.AddSingleton<MyType>();
    var sp = sc.BuildServiceProvider();
    var sut = new Foo(sp, new Other(), new Other2());

    var actual = sut.Get("a");

    Assert.That(actual, Is.InstanceOf<MyType>());
}
```

This test passes.